# Could xᵢ = x̅
???

Tags: summation

I know it's a weird question.
But this thing is confusing me.
(x̅) : average μ

①
∵ $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i) = \bar{x}$
∴ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i) = {n}\bar{x}$

②
∵ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(C) = {n}{C}$    | C = constant
∴ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(\bar{x}) = {n}{\bar{x}}$

---

From ①, ②
$(x_i) = (\bar{x})$  ???

How could this be true??
Am I missing something?

Comment: There are 66,650,000 people in the United Kingdom and let's say there are 30,000,000 houses. How many people live in 148-150 Westbourne Grove, W11, London?

Answer (score 2):

$$1+3=4$$
$$2+2=4$$

We can't conclude that $1=2$.

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: But wait, we CAN conclude that (1+3) = (2+2). Shouldn't the same apply to xᵢ and x̅? Since the sum of both is nx̅. Right?

Comment: we can't just extract one component $1$ and claim that it must be equal to $2$.

Comment: Yes but I didn't extract one component. xᵢ is all terms inside the first sum and x̅ is all the terms inside the other sum.

Comment: what do you mean by all the terms? $x_1=1, x_2=3$. Also can I check the notation, does the braces means anything?

Comment: By all terms I mean the 'elements' we are adding together. x1, x2, x3, ... , xn. And the braces is just for enclosing what we are summing up.

Comment: we have the sum are equal, but not the individual term.

Answer (score 0):

$\bar x$ is the average, so it's just some number that you can factor out of the summand:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\bar x=\bar x\sum_{i=1}^n1=\bar x\left(\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n\text{ times}}\right)=\bar x n$$

Comment: this is actually very useful. but what i was looking for is whether xᵢ = x̅ or not. Because the the sum of xᵢ = the sum of x̅ = nx̅. That's why I was confused.